# Scale out celery applications similar to Flask's blueprints

Tags: python, celery

The amount of task functions in my Celery module is growing very rapidly and they may become too unwieldy to be contained in a single module. This is a problem I faced with Flask a few years back and I solved it using Flask's blueprints.  Basically I would like to deploy the same blueprint methodology that Flask provides and group my tasks into individual modules, somehow "combine" them, and use them with a single RabbitMQ queue.  Is this possible with celery?  I hope that makes sense to everyone, not really sure how else to phrase it since I'm very new to celery.  I've tried looking in the documentations, but I hadn't really found anything (that doesn't mean it's not there though).  I would like to avoid using separate queues or brokers if possible.  Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can separate task to modules and import them using

`CELERY_IMPORTS = ('module1.tasks','module2.tasks', )` in config

In the module itself you should import Celery object itself *(named app usually)*

> The parameters of task here a purely optional, of course. But very often, when you have different modules you also want to have different queues for them

```
from .celery import app
@app.task(
    bind=True,
    queue='module1',
    options={'queue':'module1'}
)
def task1_of_module1(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try it soon. I figured if too many tasks are in a module, it would be a good indication a queue is doing too much and another queue will be required.